# When apply a function to a list, it occurs "TypeError: 'Int64Index' object is not callable"

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group by "objid", and get the first NONE-ZERO level within the same id. if within the same list, all level is 0, I will make it return 2. What I do is:

```
objid   level    color
1        0        red
1        1        blue
1        2        yellow
2        0        white
3        1        red
```

Result:

```
objid  level    
1       1        
2       2        
3       1  

def titleNot0(ls):
    try:
        Not0= ls.index(filter(lambda x:x!=0,ls)[0])
        return ls[Not0]
    except IndexError:
        return 2
userTitle = JobData.groupby("candidate_id")["TitleLevel"].apply(titleNot0)
```

I have tried on some simple list like: `x=[0,1,2],  titleNot0(x)`. It works. But if I apply the function to the groupby, it returns "TypeError". Please help me to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: maybe it's because when you apply this to a list `ls[x]` returns an integer, when you apply this to a DataFrame, `ls[x]` returns a Series.
Try `return Series([2])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error lies in line `ls.index(filter(lambda x:x!=0,ls)[0])`.

Result of `filter(lambda x:x!=0,ls)[0]` equals `1`, and `ls.index(1)` is invalid expression. This is so as ls is `Series` object and `Series.index` is not callable, as contrary to `list.index` in your working case.

To be applicable in case of DataFrame, modify your function to

```
def titleNot0(ls):
    try:
        return filter(lambda x:x!=0,ls)[0]
    except IndexError: 
        return 2
```

and invoke as

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,2,3],[0,1,2,0,1]]).T
>>> df.columns = list('AB')
>>> df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(titleNot0)
A
1    1
2    2
3    1
Name: B, dtype: int64
```